# how can i play a sound when device receive an C2DM message

Tags: android, audio, notifications, android-c2dm

i have read for hours about how to start play a sound the way i want
but i cannot find an answer.

Here goes,
When device receive a C2DM push im displaying a `Notification`.
User can click the `Notfication`and my activity start.

Everything works grate.

Now I would like to create a phone-call-type of ring-sound
so it sounds like there's an incoming Voice call.

User pick up phone and notice my `Notification` presses it
and the sound stop playing.

Or even better, the C2DM message trigger my activity to start
with a phone-call-type of ring-sound.

When user touch the phone the sound stop playing

any help in any direction would be grate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `sound` data member of your `Notification` to a `Uri` pointing to the ringtone you want to have played when the `Notification` is displayed. Ideally, you let the user pick their own ringtone (e.g., via a `RingtonePreference`) rather than forcing a certain ringtone on them.

> Or even better, the C2DM message trigger my activity to start with a phone-call-type of ring-sound.

Popping up an activity like this, when the user might be in the middle of something else, is infrequently a good idea.

Comment: This works grate thanks for quick answer. For others, notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/ringer.mp3"); and add "FLAG_INSISTENT"